# Solve the recursively defined function

Tags: recursion, runtime, complexity-theory

Find the run-time complexity of the recursively defined function T(n) = T(n-1) + 3. I am completely lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this type of recursions you can apply the muster theorem: [https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~saunders/notes/recurrence-relations.pdf](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Esaunders/notes/recurrence-relations.pdf)

In your case b = a = 1 and d = 0, therefore the complexity if O(n).